# Nodejs why should constants be variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, constants

In the [node js style guide](https://github.com/felixge/node-style-guide#use-uppercase-for-constants) it says that constants should be uppercase and declared with `var` instead of `const`

Can anyone explain why is it so?
I tought that `const` was invented to declare constants !?

Also, why should they be all uppercase?

```
const FS = require('fs');
```

feels weird but

```
const SECOND = 1 * 1000;
```

feels ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This guide comes from 2011 (original source: http://nodeguide.com/style.html#constants), and at that time there wasn't es6. `const` in this guide means mozilla's const extension, that was supported by V8, but wasn't in ECMA standard or couldn't be be applied to class members.

But since this part of ES6 is pretty well supported in node.js (http://node.green/#ES2015-bindings-const) it is advised to use it to declare constants.

Bear in mind that what the const declaration does, it creates a read-only reference to a value. It DOES NOT mean that this value is innmutable, just the reference cannot be reassigned.

Answer (score 3):

Using capitalized variables for constants was used before `ES6` version. There is a common agreement to set the names of constants with uppercase to inform developers that the value of this variable **must not be changed**, another case was to set the private properties with prefix `_`.

After `ES6` there is a keyword `const` which is used to declare constants. Variables declared with `const` keyword don't let to change their value during the lifetime of the variable.

Comment: _"This style"_ is ambiguous: are you talking about `const` or the capitalization? If ES6 introduced `const`, why is there a `const` in this guide? This answer is pretty open to interpretation.

Comment: Okay, now, why is there `const` in that style guide, which was written before ES6, while `const` was only standardized in ES6?

Comment: It is a common agreement

Comment: You're missing my point: _"After `ES6` there is a keyword `const`"_ If `const` didn't exist before ES6, why is it in the guide?